# Why BufReader.read_line() is slower than stdin().read_line()?

Tags: rust, io

Recently, I'm learning how to process I/O much faster in Rust. I found 'BufReader' and 'BufWriter' in std docs, and it says these reader and writer makes frequent reading and writing much faster because it has internal buffer.

So I tried reading 1,000,000 integer data from a file separated by new line, and writing that data to stdout.

Writing 1,000,000 data with **BufWriter** was much faster than just using writeln! macro as I expected. But, in case of **BufReader**, stdin().read_line() was little much faster than BufReader.read_line().

Here is my code.

```
use std::fmt::Write as FmtWrite;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write};
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let now = SystemTime::now();

    // 324 millisec
    // let mut input = String::new();
    // io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    // let n = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap(); 
    //
    // for _ in 0..n {
    //     input.clear();
    //     io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    //     let num = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    // }

    // 484 millisec???
    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(io::stdin().lock());
    reader.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    let n = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();

    for _ in 0..n {
        input.clear();
        reader.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let num = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{}", now.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis());
}
```

And here is how my input.txt looks like.

```
1000000
1
35
620
342
5
... and more ...
```

As comments say, reading with stdin().read_line() took about 300 milliseconds but BufReader.read_line() took over 400 milliseconds reading 1,000,000 data from file.

Why BufReader is slower?
I read that stdin().read_line() locks and unlocks stdin every time it is called. But BufReader locks stdin only once when it is created. So, logically, BufReader should be much faster, right? And it has buffer too!

Did I misunderstood the use of BufReader?

Any comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [doc page for `Stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html):

> Each handle is a shared reference to a global buffer of input data to this
> process. A handle can be `lock`'d to gain full access to [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) methods
> (e.g., `.lines()`). Reads to this handle are otherwise locked with respect
> to other reads.

In other words, `Stdin` is already buffered, buffering it again will only add overhead. That being said, the most efficient solution would probably be to lock `Stdin` and work with `StdinLock` directly:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {

    let mut input = String::new();
    let mut stdin = io::stdin().lock();
    
    stdin.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    let n = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap(); 
    
    for _ in 0..n {
     input.clear();
     io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
     let num = input.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    }

}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e0e847c1e770b269abc75a22e6c419d)